# Salesforce: Read email attachments on file upload LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, fileupload, lightning-file-upload

I used lightning-file-upload to allow Users to upload files. Now, one of the use cases is, if the file is an email (.msg file type), we need to split the attachments and upload them as individual files.
Tried using a custom file upload component, but could not get a way to read the attachments.
Any ideas around how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lightning-input type="file"` to catch these files, and even upload them with [lightning-ui-record-api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-ui-record-api) via the `createRecord` function. To understand how to read a `.msg` file, you'll need Microsoft's [[MS-OXMSG]: Outlook Item (.msg) File Format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/b046868c-9fbf-41ae-9ffb-8de2bd4eec82) specification. You can use something like [MSG Reader](https://github.com/ykarpovich/msg.reader) to read the contents of the file (note: I have not reviewed this software, you may need a different once). This is the core of everything you need, but some assembly is required.